# Minimum of element's neighbour in matrix

Tags: c

I am working on a solution for this problem
There is an array A and array B.
We put elements in array A. The elements in `B[i][j]` will be the minimum of the `A[i][j]` neighbours.
Example:

```
A[3][4]=
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
2,3,4,5

B[3][4]should be:
2,1,2,3
1,2,3,4
3,2,3,4
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int min=0;
    int m,n;
    scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
    int a[m][n];
    int b[m][n];
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
      for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if (a[i+1][j]<a[i-1][j] && a[i+1][j]<a[i][j-1] && a[i+1][j]<a[i][j+1])
            min=a[i+1][j];
            else if(a[i-1][j]<a[i+1][j] && a[i-1][j]<a[i][j-1] && a[i-1][j]<a[i][j+1])
             min=a[i-1][j];
            else if (a[i][j-1]<a[i+1][j] && a[i][j-1]<a[i-1][j] && a[i][j-1]<a[i][j+1])
             min=a[i][j-1];
            else if(a[i][j+1]<a[i+1][j] && a[i][j+1]<a[i-1][j] && a[i][j+1]<a[i][j-1])
             min=a[i][j+1];

             b[i][j]=min;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: It looks like you are not handling the edges at all.
For example for `i=0` you are still using `a[i-1]`.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad how to fix the problem? I think the problem is around the edges. Any idea how to fix this solution?

Comment: @hko, how to fix this ?

Comment: You need to add extra cases for `i=0`, `i= n-1`, `j=0` and `j=n-1`. And exclude those in your min calculation for the edges. Give it a try. I'm too lazy to write you down the entire solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some problems with the edges. You need to program defensively. I will show you how you can do it for the if and will leave you the else cases to do as a practice, which are to be done very similarly. So:

```
        if ((i+1<m) && ((i==0 || a[i+1][j]<a[i-1][j]) && (j==0 || a[i+1][j]<a[i][j-1]) && (j+1==n || a[i+1][j]<a[i][j+1])))
        min=a[i+1][j];
```

The idea is that you only consider i+1 if it's not out of bounds. In that case, you compare to the other directions if it makes sense and if it's smaller than the others, then chosen as min. If such a comparison does not make sense due to the counterpart being out of bounds, then the a[i+1] defaults to smaller.

However, a much simpler approach is:

```
min = INT_MAX;
if ((i+1<m) && (a[i+1][j] < min)) min = a[i+1][j];
if ((i>0) && (a[i-1][j] < min)) min = a[i-1][j];
if ((j+1<n) && (a[i][j+1] < min)) min = a[i][j+1];
if ((j>0) && (a[i][j-1] < min)) min = a[i][j-1];
```

Simpler, right? About INT_MAX see more here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/int_max-int_min-cc-applications/